# grunt imagemin creating infinite folders and warning of empty file

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I installed in `Gruntfile.js` correctly imagemin following this [tutorial](http://24ways.org/2013/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/#fn167318486852a968d2ca848) of a our dear friend Chris Coyier. It compiles but I get two strange quircks, two issues basically...

**Issue 1:**

The images are created double or triple and this is only with one `grunt` command. Below you can see the file structure created after command grunt. Imagine if `watch` does this frequently! I need a solution for this as I would like this functionality to be automatic if possible, any help?

[image]

**Issue 2:**

The images minify correctly but I get always an error that an image is empty as you can see below. Funny thing, that image has been already worked out. I suppose if the first problem is solved this issue will most probably be solved. Below the terminal output.

Terminal output:

```
Running "imagemin:dynamic" (imagemin) task
✔ images/245x600.gif (saved 1.22 kB)
✔ images/300x500.gif (saved 1.38 kB)
✔ images/310x600.gif (saved 1.46 kB)
✔ images/400x600.gif (saved 1.85 kB)
✔ images/660x342.gif (saved 2.54 kB)
✔ images/940x487.gif (saved 3.69 kB)
✔ images/960x410.gif (saved 3.67 kB)
✔ images/build/build/245x600.gif (saved 1.22 kB)
✔ images/build/build/300x500.gif (saved 1.38 kB)

Warning: gifsicle: images/build/245x600.gif: empty file
```

As asked here is my Gruntfile.js configuration:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // 1. All configuration goes here
    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // 2. Configuration for concatinating files goes here.

        // Concatonate various files into one
        concat: {
            dist: {
                src: [
                    'js/vendor/*.js', // All JS in the libs folder
                    'js/plugin.js', // All JS in the libs folder
                    'js/global.js'  // This specific file
                ],
                dest: 'js/build/production.js',
            }
        },

        // Creates a minified version of the javascript files of the project
        uglify: {
            build: {
                src: ['js/vendor/*.js', 'js/plugin.js', 'js/global.js'],
                dest: 'js/build/production.min.js'
            }
        },

         // Minifies automatically the images of the project
        // imagemin: {
        //     dynamic: {
        //         files: [{
        //             expand: true,
        //             cwd: 'images/',
        //             src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
        //             dest: 'images/build/'
        //         }]
        //     }
        // },

        // Watches for changes done on the project and builds the commands if neccesary
        watch: {

             options: {
                livereload: true,
            },

            scripts: {
                files: ['js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['concat', 'uglify'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                },
            },

            sass: {
                dist: {
                    options: {
                        style: 'compressed'
                    },
                    files: {
                        'css/build/style.css': 'sass/style.scss'
                    }
                }
            },

            css: {
                files: ['css/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                }
            }
        }

    });

    // 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    // 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify', 'sass', 'compass', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Please add in the relevant code from your Gruntfile to this question, we'll need that to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @jakarella I just added my Gruntfile.js. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I had the same issue and figured it out. The issue was, running grunt the first time would create the files and folders correctly, but the second time it would grab all the previously minified files as well and try to re-minify.

The imagemin section of my Gruntfile.js now looks like this:

```
imagemin: {
        dynamic: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'img/',
                src: ['*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                dest: 'img/build'
            }]
        }
    },
```

I believe the cwd is where you add your source directory, and your src is relative to that. So I replaced **/* with just *. That way, grunt only looks inside of my img directory for images, instead of going into child directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the Grunt file, I see your problem now... you are placing the minified images back into the folder which you are using as the source. So the process takes an image file from the `images` directory, minifies it, then places the minified version into the `images` folder... and then the process repeats, thus it tries to minifiy the already minified file. Instead, simply put the minified versions into a different folder:

```
imagemin: {
    dynamic: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'images/',
            src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
            dest: 'build/imagemin' // <-- don't make the destination the same as src!
        }]
    }
},
```